# how to vertical align <p> and <div>, position them without table-cell property

Tags: html, css

I want to position my text so it is vertical align in the middle with ch-grid `<div>` (that circle color thing).

Is it possible to make it without giving `<p>` any display attribute because when I position it I will give it `display:none` so I can fade it out and do something later.

Sorry but I tried a lot of thing and nothing works for me. Thanks a lot.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-push-6"> 
    <div class="ch-grid">
           <p>Who are we?</p>            
         <div class="ch-item ch-img-1">
             <div class="ch-info ch-info-1">
               <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>    
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
body{
padding-top: 100px; 
height: 100%;
font-family: helvetica, sans-serif, verdana;
}

.ch-grid {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 5vh;
width:400px;
height: 100px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.ch-grid:after,
.ch-item:before {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.ch-grid:after {
  clear: both;
 }

.ch-item {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 cursor: default;
 box-shadow: 
    inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255,255,255,0.6),
    0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 }

p {
 width: 100px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
 .ch-img-1 { 
 background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dhcrccc1b/image/upload /c_scale,h_100,q_46,w_100/v1479836467/Bike%20page/Free-HD-artisticwallpaper4.jpg");
}   

.ch-info {

background: rgba(218, 173, 77, 0.8);
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
border-radius: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transform: scale(0);
 }

.ch-info-2{
 background: rgba(157, 151, 138, 0.8);
 }

 .ch-info-3{
 background: rgba(126, 154, 220, 0.8);
 }

 .ch-info-4{
background: rgba(76, 166, 37, 0.8);
  }

.ch-info i {
margin-top: 15px;
color: white;
}

.ch-item:hover {
box-shadow: 
    inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
    0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.ch-item:hover .ch-info {
transform: scale(1);
opacity: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Chainervk/qg7en3cs/

Comment: `line-height: 100px` (the same as div's height).

Comment: instead display:none and absolute, use displaytable or inline-block and visibility or opacity to hide your thing , so it remains in the flow and it is not jumping all around when hidden :)

Comment: to me display table works fine if you get rid of absolute positionning http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yVXpWQ (bootstrap & font awsome included in demo)

Comment: @GCyrillus thank you it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use flexbox with `align-items:center`: https://jsfiddle.net/qg7en3cs/5/? It aligns the direct children of the container without need to change their `display` value.

Also, what is the use of

```
.ch-grid:after,
.ch-item:before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

.ch-grid:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

in your initial demo? It looks exactly like 'micro clearfix' hack, but clearfix hacks are needed only if layout is built with floats, but I don't see any float in your demo.

Answer (score 0):

add `top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` in the `p` tag to get it vertically aligned in middle

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
margin: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

**Demo:-**

```css
body{
padding-top: 100px; 
height: 100%;
font-family: helvetica, sans-serif, verdana;
}

.ch-grid {
    position: relative;
    
    text-align: center;
   margin-bottom: 5vh;
   width:400px;
   height: 100px;
   display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.ch-grid:after,
.ch-item:before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

.ch-grid:after {
    clear: both;
}

.ch-item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
    box-shadow: 
        inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255,255,255,0.6),
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
p {
  
width: 100px;
vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  margin:0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
}
.ch-img-1 { 
    background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dhcrccc1b/image/upload/c_scale,h_100,q_46,w_100/v1479836467/Bike%20page/Free-HD-artistic-wallpaper4.jpg");
}   

.ch-img-2 { 
    background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dhcrccc1b/image/upload/c_scale,h_100,q_41,w_100/v1479836446/Bike%20page/Fantastic-Artistic-Pictures5.jpg");

}

.ch-img-3 { 
    background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dhcrccc1b/image/upload/c_scale,h_100,q_43,w_100/v1479836455/Bike%20page/Artistic-Pictures-HD.jpg");
}

.ch-img-4 { 
    background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dhcrccc1b/image/upload/c_scale,h_100,q_31,w_100/v1479836467/Bike%20page/Artistic-Images-For-Desktop2.jpg");
}

.ch-info {

    background: rgba(218, 173, 77, 0.8);
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transform: scale(0);
}

.ch-info-2{
     background: rgba(157, 151, 138, 0.8);
}

.ch-info-3{
    background: rgba(126, 154, 220, 0.8);
}

.ch-info-4{
    background: rgba(76, 166, 37, 0.8);
}

.ch-info i {
    margin-top: 15px;
    color: white;
}

.ch-item:hover {
    box-shadow: 
        inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.ch-item:hover .ch-info {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-push-6"> 
           
          <div class="ch-grid">
               <p>Who are we?</p>          
       <div class="ch-item ch-img-1">
        <div class="ch-info ch-info-1">
       <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </div>
       </div>
       </div>
        <div class="ch-grid">
            <p>Bikes!</p>
          <div class="ch-item ch-img-2 ">
        <div class="ch-info ch-info-2">
         <i class="fa fa-bicycle fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </div>
       </div>
       </div>

          <div class="ch-grid">
           <p>Parts.</p>
         <div class="ch-item ch-img-3">
        <div class="ch-info ch-info-3">
      <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
    
       <div class="ch-grid">
         <p>Why ride?</p>
        <div class="ch-item ch-img-4">
        <div class="ch-info ch-info-4">
      <i class="fa fa-arrows fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div> 
                  
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: it worked on <p> but that's not what i was looking for, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `div.ch-item` upwards.

```
.ch-item {
    margin-top: -75px;
}
```

Here is the snippet:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif, verdana;
}
.ch-grid {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ch-grid:after,
.ch-item:before {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.ch-grid:after {
  clear: both;
}
.ch-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: -75px;
}
p {
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ch-img-1 {
  background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dhcrccc1b/image/upload/c_scale,h_100,q_46,w_100/v1479836467/Bike%20page/Free-HD-artistic-wallpaper4.jpg");
}
.ch-img-2 {
  background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dhcrccc1b/image/upload/c_scale,h_100,q_41,w_100/v1479836446/Bike%20page/Fantastic-Artistic-Pictures5.jpg");
}
.ch-img-3 {
  background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dhcrccc1b/image/upload/c_scale,h_100,q_43,w_100/v1479836455/Bike%20page/Artistic-Pictures-HD.jpg");
}
.ch-img-4 {
  background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dhcrccc1b/image/upload/c_scale,h_100,q_31,w_100/v1479836467/Bike%20page/Artistic-Images-For-Desktop2.jpg");
}
.ch-info {
  background: rgba(218, 173, 77, 0.8);
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(0);
}
.ch-info-2 {
  background: rgba(157, 151, 138, 0.8);
}
.ch-info-3 {
  background: rgba(126, 154, 220, 0.8);
}
.ch-info-4 {
  background: rgba(76, 166, 37, 0.8);
}
.ch-info i {
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: white;
}
.ch-item:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.ch-item:hover .ch-info {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-push-6">

        <div class="ch-grid">
          <p>Who are we?</p>
          <div class="ch-item ch-img-1">
            <div class="ch-info ch-info-1">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ch-grid">
          <p>Bikes!</p>
          <div class="ch-item ch-img-2 ">
            <div class="ch-info ch-info-2">
              <i class="fa fa-bicycle fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ch-grid">
          <p>Parts.</p>
          <div class="ch-item ch-img-3">
            <div class="ch-info ch-info-3">
              <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ch-grid">
          <p>Why ride?</p>
          <div class="ch-item ch-img-4">
            <div class="ch-info ch-info-4">
              <i class="fa fa-arrows fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```